# Preventing loop from updating all sub dictionary values

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

Been googling and trying for weeks now, but haven't come across a solution.

I have a loop that goes through a list of entries and tries to make a dictionary of dictionaries of them.
My loop first checks whether the key exists within our main dictionary - if not, it creates the key and desired sub-dictionaries - it then checks which sub-dictionary value it needs to update. Below is a simplification of the code.

I have the following data in excel sheet:

```
         A.                B.                C.                
1    product1            item1              used
2    product2            item2              new
3    product1            item3              removed
4    product1            item3              removed
5    product3            item5              new
6    product4            item2              new
7    product2            item1              used
8    product1            item3              new
9    product4            item2              removed
10   product5            item1              used
```

So now the loop should go through each row and determine for each product how many used, new and removed of each items there are.

```
Sub example()
Set test_dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For i = 1 To 10
        product_name = Cells(i, 1).Value
        item_name = Cells(i, 2).Value
        item_status = Cells(i, 3).Value

        If test_dict.Exists(product_name) = False Then
            Set item_dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
                item_dict.Add item_name, 0
            Set status_dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
                status_dict.Add "used", item_dict
                status_dict.Add "new", item_dict
                status_dict.Add "removed", item_dict
            test_dict.Add product_name, status_dict
        End If
        test_dict(product_name)(item_status)(item_name) = test_dict(product_name)(item_status)(item_name) + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

It should produce something like this:

```
test_dict
   | 
   |--> "product1" 
   |       |--> "used"  
   |       |      |-> "item1" = 1
   |       |      '-> "item3" = 0
   |       |-> "new"        
   |       |      |-> "item1" = 0
   |       |      '-> "item3" = 1
   |       '-> "removed"        
   |              |-> "item1" = 0
   |              '-> "item3" = 2    
   |--> "product2" (etc.)
```

But for whatever reason, my loop keeps updating all subdicts i.e.

```
test_dict
   | 
   |--> "product1" 
   |       |--> "used"  
   |       |      |-> "item1" = 1 *<-- correct value for item1*
   |       |      '-> "item3" = 2 *<-- false value for item3*
   |       |-> "new"        
   |       |      |-> "item1" = 1 *<-- false value for item1*
   |       |      '-> "item3" = 2 *<-- false value for item3*
   |       '-> "removed"        
   |              |-> "item1" = 1 *<-- false value for item1*
   |              '-> "item3" = 2 *<-- correct value for item3*   
   |--> "product2" (etc.)
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?
I've checked my code over and over again, I've tried different methods of doing the same, but somehow I always end up at the problem.

Comment: Are you supposed to produce a dictionaries such that, for example, product-Item3 -removed   = 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            status_dict.Add "used", item_dict
            status_dict.Add "new", item_dict
            status_dict.Add "removed", item_dict
```

You are adding the **same** dictionary object `item_dict` 3 times here.

So if you +1 in any of the 3 instances, it will affect all of them.

To avoid this, you would need to create a **new** dictionary object for each of the 3 instances.

Edit: for example

```
Set status_dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
For x = 1 To 3
    Set item_dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    item_dict.Add item_name, 0

    strStatus = Choose(x, "used", "new", "removed")
    status_dict.Add strStatus, item_dict
Next x
test_dict.Add product_name, status_dict
```

Comment: Oh man, it was so simple!! Worked perfectly! Thanks man! I had no idea it kind of links these dict-objects to one another. Always thought it'd create them as copy. Thanks again! This is a huge relief! Have a nice weekend! :)